# Sonar 3.4.1 Configuration is not showing CodeCoverage category -- why?

Tags: configuration, code-coverage, sonarqube, cobertura, jacoco

I am using Sonar 3.4.1, however the CodeCoverage Settings are not appearing on the General Settings configuration.

```
General Settings
  Category
    CheckStyle
    Cobertura
    <CodeCoverage is missing??>
    Database Cleaner
    ...
```

Has anyone seen this situation before, where CodeCoverage is not mentioned in the GeneralSettings panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no CodeCoverage category anymore, as this is too generic: code coverage settings depend on the language you're using.

For Java, you'll find the possibility to choose your code coverage engine in the "Java" category, and then you'll be able to customize the coverage engine in its own category.